# Accessing a protected Network Folder from a Windows Service

Tags: c#, networking, ftp, windows-services, networkcredentials

I am experiencing the following issue:
I need to copy some files from a Network Folder, using a Windows Services. I have read around about Service Sessions, and User Sessions, but still haven't found a case similar to mine:

```
Network Folder: \\192.168.10.1\Parent\Folder  
User to access the folder: administrator  
Pwd to access the folder: folderpwd
```

From the user session i can access it with success, user the reported credentials(a login popup is showed before accessing it)

```
Windows Credentials: (Windows Server 2003 R2 x86)  
Windows User: administrator  
Windows Pwd: P@ssword
```

Windows Service: `InputMonitor (written in c#)`

Under which user should i run the service Input Monitor ?
I have tried different combination, but still i am not able to access the folder.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this on a workgroup or domain? Have you tried passing along as the username: domain\administrator. With out a pre-qualifier the windows PC will assume you are trying to do a local auth request IF the account administrator exists in the local auth context.